# Reading Rails Debugger Output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

Typically, Rails Debugger outputs variables in a way that I can read. I just got this response, though, and there are a couple of things about the syntax that I can't parse:

```
> eval @search
> Ransack::Search<class: Organization, base: Grouping <conditions: [Condition <attributes: [nil], predicate: eq, values: [nil]>], combinator: and>>
```

First off, what do the `<` and `>` represent here? Secondly, what is the meaning of the free-floating `Condition` inside of the array?

I would typically look in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) for an answer, but I can't find anything there to answer these questions.

Comment: what does `@search.inspect` give you?

Comment: The same result, unfortunately.